# Change the timeout from 30 sec in wso2 esb 4.8.0

Tags: apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I am trying to change the wso2 esb response timeout which is by default 30 sec. I have tried changing the timeout in all the wso2 config files from 30000 to 60000. But it is still not helpful. I added the following in the axis2.xml:

```html
<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT" locked="false">108000000</parameter>
<parameter name="CONNECTION_TIMEOUT">120000</parameter>
```

But even that was not helpful.

I even had set JMS_WAIT_REPLY property to 60000. But still it gives a timeout in 30000ms.
**I am using JMS transport**. Please let me know if you have any information regarding this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to check the JMS transport settings detailed here [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+JMS+Transport).  You should also set the synapse properties to increase the timeout.  The synapse.global_timeout_interval in /repository/conf/synapse.properties .  This is a synapse (ESB-level) configuration.  It affects multiple transport types.

To increase the timeout significantly, you need to increase all three timeout values.

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+JMS+Transport) [https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+JMS+Transport][1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+JMS+Transport)

Comment: If I make changes in the synapse.properties file, it increases the global timeout. But the maximum time in which the responding queue is expected to respond still remains 30 sec.